# Count result array to string conversion error in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, string, codeigniter

I am using this method in my model to get a count result from my database:

```
function members($group_id)
{
    $this->db->where('group_id',$group_id);
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(group_id) FROM member');    
    return $query;
 }
```

And in my controller there is this method:

```
   function total_members ()
   {
       $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id');
       $this->load->model('Member_model');
       $members = $this->Member_model->members($group_id);
       echo $members;
   }
```

And am getting this weird error which says:

> Severity: 4096
>   Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string
>   Filename: controllers/Payment.php

Comment: in controller add `print_r($members)` and check output first of all

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Model

```
function members($group_id) {
    return $this->db->get_where('member', array('group_id' => $group_id))->num_rows();
}
```

Controller

```
function total_members() {
    $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id');
    $this->load->model('member_model');
    $members = $this->member_model->members($group_id);
    print_r($members);
}
```

In codeigniter there is `num_rows()` to count the rows. For more information check the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) .

Comment: That will work but the query will return all the rows first. By using the sql function `COUNT` in query only one row (in this case) will be returned. A lot less resource intensive and likely much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a result set which requires another call. In this case I suggest `row()`. Try these revised functions.

```
function members($group_id)
{
    $this->db->where('group_id', $group_id);
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(group_id) as count FROM member');
    return $query->row();
}

function total_members()
{
    $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id');
    $this->load->model('Member_model');
    $members = $this->Member_model->members($group_id);
    if(isset($members))
    {
        echo $members->count;
    }
}
```

Learn about the different kinds of result sets [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)